# Oracle Join Using + derived column

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm optimising for readability. The SQL join 'using' syntax is syntactically less verbose than 'on' where applicable. I'd ideally like to write:

```
select *, 
  col1 + col2 as derviedCol 
from table1 join table2 using (joinCol1, joinCol2)
```

however oracle (and I suspect other DBs) won't let you use a table identifier when using the 'using' syntax (ORA-00904) so the next best thing I can do is:

```
select t.*, 
  col1 + col2 as derviedCol 
from (
  select * from table1 join table2 using (joinCol1, joinCol2)
) t
```

or

```
select t1.*, t2.*, 
  col1 + col2 as derviedCol 
from table1 t1 
join table2 t2 on 
  t1.joinCol1 = t2.joinCol1 
  and t1.joinCol2 = t2.joinCol2
```

Can someone suggest a more concise syntax?

Comment: somewhat related to this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1797778/oracle-join-using-subquery-ora-00904-string-invalid-identifier
which suggests there isn't a cleaner solution :(

Comment: Duplicate of [Oracle JOIN USING + Subquery : ora-00904 string: invalid identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1797778/oracle-join-using-subquery-ora-00904-string-invalid-identifier)

Comment: And the question is? Query 1 is invalid SQL, query 2 and 3 are valid, returning similar result (USING query has fewer columns.)

Comment: The implicit question was: can someone suggest a more concise way of writing 2 or 3.

Answer (score 0):

I challenge the opening statement and hold that "using syntax" are LESS "clean". Even if there are common names to join through, and the natural join "hides" the "duplicated column name", the derived table can still contain columns of the same name (e.g. "shortname" seen below which exists in both but isn't part of the join).

Additionally, if the 'using join' specifies both columns, then both columns get returned, even if they have the same column name.

For a few extra characters in the join syntax, you get a much more precise (and flexible) approach which can be used in any query without needing special data model conditions. I also contend that syntactical consistency of using ON style joins leads to less variability and hence easier maintenance.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/af9f0/9)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE COUNTRIES
    (COUNTRY varchar2(9), ISOCODE varchar2(3), SHORTNAME varchar2(4))
;

INSERT ALL 
    INTO COUNTRIES (COUNTRY, ISOCODE, SHORTNAME)
         VALUES ('Aruba', 'ABW', NULL)
    INTO COUNTRIES (COUNTRY, ISOCODE, SHORTNAME)
         VALUES ('Australia', 'AUS', 'Oz')
    INTO COUNTRIES (COUNTRY, ISOCODE, SHORTNAME)
         VALUES ('Austria', 'AUT', NULL)
SELECT * FROM dual
;

CREATE TABLE CITIES
    (ISOCODE varchar2(3), CITY varchar2(9), SHORTNAME varchar2(3))
;

INSERT ALL 
    INTO CITIES (ISOCODE, CITY, SHORTNAME)
         VALUES ('AUS', 'Melbourne', 'Mel')
SELECT * FROM dual
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select * from countries join cities using (ISOCODE)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/af9f0/9/0)**:

```
| ISOCODE |   COUNTRY | SHORTNAME |      CITY | SHORTNAME |
|---------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
|     AUS | Australia |        Oz | Melbourne |       Mel |
```

**Query 2**:

```
select * from countries join cities using (ISOCODE,ISOCODE)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/af9f0/9/1)**:

```
| ISOCODE | ISOCODE |   COUNTRY | SHORTNAME |      CITY | SHORTNAME |
|---------|---------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
|     AUS |     AUS | Australia |        Oz | Melbourne |       Mel |
```

**Query 3**:

```
select * from countries left join cities using (ISOCODE)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/af9f0/9/2)**:

```
| ISOCODE |   COUNTRY | SHORTNAME |      CITY | SHORTNAME |
|---------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
|     AUS | Australia |        Oz | Melbourne |       Mel |
|     AUT |   Austria |    (null) |    (null) |    (null) |
|     ABW |     Aruba |    (null) |    (null) |    (null) |
```

**Query 4**:

```
select * from countries left join cities using (ISOCODE,ISOCODE)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/af9f0/9/3)**:

```
| ISOCODE | ISOCODE |   COUNTRY | SHORTNAME |      CITY | SHORTNAME |
|---------|---------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
|     AUS |     AUS | Australia |        Oz | Melbourne |       Mel |
|     AUT |     AUT |   Austria |    (null) |    (null) |    (null) |
|     ABW |     ABW |     Aruba |    (null) |    (null) |    (null) |
```

Comment: I see your point and have amended my statement to read "syntactically less verbose". I have full control over my data model and hence don't run into the edge cases you mentioned above. the 'on' syntax while more standard and explicit can become cumbersome to read when joining on many columns. I'm not saying the natural join is a silver bullet but is handy in many cases. I'd just like to know if there's a more concise syntax for my code above, I'd like to avoid a philosophical / flame war debate over which is better.

Comment: Then you have answered your own question. No; there is no "syntactically less verbose" way via the `natural join` route. I'm not sure I would characterize my comment above as a flame, however, I do hold the opinion that the effort you will expend to use natural joins is not effort well spent, particularly when others less versed in your approach get to maintain that code.

Comment: The opening statement does not talk about "natural joins" - the `using()` clause explicitly lists the join column in contrast to the `natural join` operator. `from a join b using (x,y)` is something very different to `from a natural join b`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Good point. Mentally I lump these things together (as join types I don't use). So I made a small edit. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign aliases and use those to qualify column calculations; e.g.

```
select co.shortname || '.' || ci.shortname as mycol
from countries co
join cities ci using (ISOCODE);
```

or simply qualify the columns by their respective tables names; e.g.

```
select countries.shortname || '.' || cities.shortname as mycol
from countries
join cities using (ISOCODE);
```

*Not sure if this complies with your definition of "less verbose"*

Comment: it is the * I'm after unfortunately, not just the derived column.

Comment: Well, then you hit this wall: http://psoug.org/oraerror/ORA-25154.htm Eventually you may reach the decision that `using` just isn't worth the trouble because of all the restrictions it imposes.